# Jenkins (in a Docker container) - npm install fails because of ... npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, futime

Tags: docker, jenkins, npm

When running 'npm install' in a Jenkins Docker container I get these errors:

> ```
> [INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (npm install) @ geosolutions ---
> npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/aproject2/node_modules/.staging/schema-utils-bdceae78/package.json'
> npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/aproject2/node_modules/.staging/schema-utils-bdceae78/README.md'
> ...(and many lines like) ...
> npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, futime
> npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, futime
> npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, futime
> npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, futime
> ```

No 'node_modules' are generated. Only a few in node_modules/.staging.

When going into the Jenkins Docker container, I can fix this by manually performing:

- rm -rf node_modules
- rm -f package-lock.json
- npm install

The next time I have to skip the 'npm install' step, so directly start with the 'ng build'. Then everything works OK. Of couse - this is not a decent workaround. **Therefore this is NOT a duplicate question.**

**How can I do a good 'npm install'?**

In my Jenkins container I have a Node/Npm installation. Npm is 6.5 and node is either 8, 9, 10 or 11. All with the newest npm 6.5.

My Jenkins image contains this code for adding npm/nodejs to it:

```
RUN apt-get install -y curl \
  && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | bash - \
  && apt-get install -y nodejs \
  && curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
```

**Update:** Today I had the same issue at the office. Two different Jenkinsjobs start the very same Maven task with 'npm install'. One is OK, the other not. One Jenkinsjob is started via a multibranch, the other as a regular pipeline. Hmm, very strange.

I think this has to do with the operating environment, so the $PATH, environment variables, etc.

Comment: To confirm only dependency `schema-utils` has this issue, or any dependency has same issue.  If only `schema-utils`, maybe you need install  C compiler like gcc required by `schema-utils`.

Comment: Have you tried all the solution mentioned here.... https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/866

Comment: Tried a number of options. Tried the newest nodejs/npm which was available at https://github.com/nodesource/distributions. We don't get any sqlite errors. Any new suggestion I have added to the question.

Comment: Looks like you have the same hook attached on both the jobs, so just disable the one which doesn't work

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: Honestly, I'd advise you to run Jenkins Master as a container, and to make it connect to a Jenkins Slave container (embedding Node). That way the slave would always begin with a clean environment, containing only the necesary dependencies, and the isolation level it needs.

Comment: One more workaround which always works for me. I just reset docker to the default settings. It looks like there are some internal docker's lock files which got corrupted and reset resolves the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After talking to a number of experts and reading a lot of forum posts, the following is the proposed 'workaround'. Many people use the workaround. I hope you have a better solution than this one. At least, this workaround works.

Following the workaround, building Angular in Maven can go like this: first clear the workspace, especially removing the node_modules folder and the package-lock.json file. Then start the npm install and the build action.

If you are in a hurry after creating your first build, just add a property 'maven.exec.skip', and start Maven with the -P maven.exec.skip=true. Then the cleaning and npm install step are skipped ;-)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>npm clear workspace</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>initialize</phase>
        <configuration>
          <skip>${maven.exec.skip}</skip>
          <executable>rm</executable>
          <arguments>
            <argument>-rf</argument>
            <argument>node_modules</argument>
            <argument>package-lock.json</argument>
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>npm install</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>initialize</phase>
        <configuration>
          <skip>${maven.exec.skip}</skip>
          <executable>npm</executable>
          <arguments>
            <argument>install</argument>
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>build Angular production code</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
        <configuration>
          <executable>npm</executable>
          <arguments>
            <argument>run</argument>
            <argument>build</argument>
            <!--<argument>&#45;&#45;prod</argument>-->
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Facing the Same Issue steps to resolve your issue.

> npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory

> steps used to solve:-
> I) in Jenkins job go to your directory and do

> **rm -rf package-lock.json**

> **npm -i**